# Создан текстовый файл , как к нему обратиться в программе и возможна ли его корректировка из основной программы?

Tags: c++

```
include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, a, b, n;
    unsigned char ch1, ch2;
    char str_spisok[29][19], str[19];
    system("chcp 1251 > nul");


    cout << "Введите число фамилий в списке (29 или меньше): ";              

 //количесво фамилий 29 или меньше.
    cin >> n;                                                                

  //29 отвечает 30 фамилиям

    cout << "\t"<<" Вводим список класса: \n";
    for (i=0;i<=n;i++)  gets(str_spisok[i]);
       for (a=1;a<n;a++)
        for (b=n;b>=a;b--){
          ch1=str_spisok[b-1][0];
         ch2=str_spisok[b][0];
         if (ch1>ch2){
                      strcpy(str,str_spisok[b-1]);
                      strcpy(str_spisok[b-1],str_spisok[b]);
                      strcpy(str_spisok[b],str);
                      }
         }

 cout << "\t  Список отсортирован:\n ";
 for (i=0;i<=n;i++) cout <<"  \t"<< str_spisok[i]<< "\n";

system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

Создан текстовый файл , как к нему обратиться в программе и возможна ли его 
корректировка из основной программы ?

Comment: Читайте об `fstream`...

Comment: Ответ понятен, пошел разбираться.

Comment: вы второй раз задаете тот же вопрос,  с разной формулировкой. Ваш код и вопрос имеют что то общее?...

Comment: Вопрос исправил.

Answer (score 2):

Вам так надо было сделать?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include "string.h"
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, a, b, n;
    unsigned char ch1, ch2;
    char str_spisok[29][19], str[19];
    ofstream file;
    file.open("/home/oem/file1.txt", ofstream::app | ofstream::ate);
    //system("chcp 1251 > nul");

    cout << "Введите число фамилий в списке (29 или меньше): ";

    //количесво фамилий 29 или меньше.
    cin >> n;

    //29 отвечает 30 фамилиям

    cout << "\t" << " Вводим список класса: \n";
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) cin >> (str_spisok[i]);
    for (a = 1; a < n; a++)
        for (b = n; b >= a; b--) {
            ch1 = str_spisok[b - 1][0];
            ch2 = str_spisok[b][0];
            if (ch1 > ch2) {
                strcpy(str, str_spisok[b - 1]);
                strcpy(str_spisok[b - 1], str_spisok[b]);
                strcpy(str_spisok[b], str);
            }
        }

    file << "\t  Список отсортирован:\n ";
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) file << "  \t" << str_spisok[i] << "\n";
    file.flush();
    file.close();

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

P.S. Если вам нужно писать не в конец файла то при открытии файла уберите флаг ofstream::app. И вообще если нужно управление открытием то вот основные флаги http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode.

Comment: Да, Да, Да. Вот теперь все ясно. Спасибо.

Comment: Если ответ вас устроил, пожалуйста, не забудьте пометить его как ответ на вопрос и закрыть вопрос.

Comment: Где прочитать как закрыть вопрос?

Comment: Слева от моего поста нажмите галочку, она должна загореться зелёным.